# How do I create multiline texts in kivyMD

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am trying to create a simple app with multiline text, but I keep getting a 'Invalid indentation (too many levels)'. Here is my main.py file;

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp


class TwoScreenApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return


TwoScreenApp().run()
```

And here is my .kv file. I would appreciate any sort of help, Thanks.

```
MDScreen:
    md_bg_color: (255/255, 255/255, 255/255, 1)

MDLabel:
    halign: 'center'
    text: """With the production of the Model T automobile,
            \nHenry Ford had an unforeseen and tremendous
            \nimpact on American life. He became regarded
            \nas an apt symbol of the transition from an
            \nagricultural to an industrial America.
        """
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
MDLabel:
    halign: 'center'
    text:
        """With the production of the Model T automobile,
        Henry Ford had an unforeseen and tremendous
        impact on American life. He became regarded
        as an apt symbol of the transition from an
        agricultural to an industrial America."""
```

For some reason, putting the multiline literal starting on a separate line makes it work.

Comment: thanks for your help, I tried it but I am getting this error message - if current_property[:3] == 'on_':
 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: I have discovered the issue, it was a wrong indentation, thanks a lot for your help.